# Tmux: how to specify session in new-window

Tags: tmux

When I run `tmux new-window` from a script outside of my current tmux session, how can I specify which session the new window should be associated with?

Answer (score 18):

Though not very clearly documented, it turns out windows can be specified as `session-name:window-number`, so specifying `tmux new-window -t SESSION:` results in creating a new window in the session.  The session name or default number may be used.

Answer (score 13):

Just improving @David's answer, because it wan't very clear for me and I spent some time investigating this.

Suppose, we created a session and a window with this command:

```
tmux new-session -d -s my-session-1 -n my-window-1 'sleep 10000'
```

To add a new window into it:

```
tmux new-window -n my-window-2 -t my-session-1: 'sleep 10000'
```

(notice the colon after the session name)